# How can I effectively use node-pre-gyp's --runtime option?

Tags: node.js, electron

The node-pre-gyp [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp#options) says that the command line has a `--runtime` option, to build the library for node-webkit or electron. I would like to use this option, but there are a couple of issues:

- In my binding.gyp file, how can I check which of those options were used? Some build options need to change for it to work properly with electron.
- How can I make sure that when installing under election, it downloads the electron package instead of the Node packages? The [versioning section](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp#versioning) of the documentation lists several variables, but "runtime" is not among them.

Comment: Related to second part of your question, when using PouchDB with Electron with a leveldb backend, the node_modules are installed and then as a postInstall step node-gyp is run. https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-electron#using-leveldb-via-leveldown You could follow a similar approach..?

Comment: Those instructions show how to compile and link the native extension against Electron. But in my case, I *also* need the gyp file to compile a target differently when compiling for electron.